# How to get form post data in the same page after form submitting and redirecting?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hello all i have a page which had Add price button for each product. When customers visits the page he likes to bid his own amount so he will click on add price button. One form will show and he will enter some price and he will submit the form. When he submitted the form he will redirected to the products page.

Now what my problem is i want to show how much he price he quoted on that specific product after redirecting to that page. How can i do that. I am looking for ideas.

Note: I am developing this application on codeIgntier framework..........

Comment: Use javascript or jquery

Comment: I am not that good at both of those. Can you say little bit more specific

Comment: Store it in a cookie or session.

Answer (score 1):

Using Codeigniter it is easy in the controller you can do it like this

```
<?php
Class Test Extends CI_Controller
{

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function index()
    {
        $data   =   array();
        if($post_data = $this->input->post())
        {
            $data['status'] =   $post_data['status']
        }
        $this->load->view('my_view',$data);
    }

}
```

And in The View

```
<html>
    <body>
    <?php
    if(isset($status)){
        echo $status;
    }
    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: raheel thanks for the reply this i know but this won't work in my case because this will work for one form. But i am using same form for all products so when you show the status for first products it works well. What about second one when user submits for second product that will overwrite the value of first one also because you are using same variable to show for first product also.........

Comment: put a hidden field in the form where you can increment the number and check that number in the controller and then display status or other things according to it

Answer (score 1):

**controller** side

```
 public function get_data()
{
    $data= $_POST;
    $this->load->view('your_view_page',$data);
}
```

Comment: CodeIgniter has its own helper methods for input collection.

Comment: yes, we can get data by many ways

Answer (score 0):

You can change the status name depending on your different product. You can use prefix or suffix for the name of status so it may differ from other names in array.

Like,

```
$data['status1'] =   $post_data['status1']
$data['status2'] =   $post_data['status2']
$data['status3'] =   $post_data['status3']
```